# Combining rollapply() and weighted.mean() in a data.table apply() for multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, lapply, rollapply

I am trying to compute weighted averages for various columns in data.table with `rollapply()` and `weighted.mean()` as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(id = rep(c(1,2), each = 5),
                 var1 = 1:10,
                 var2 = 11:20)
col_names <- c('var1', 'var2')
DT[, (col_names) := lapply(.SD, 
                           function(x) rollapplyr(x, 
                                                  width = 3,
                                                  weighted.mean, 
                                                  w = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5),
                                                  align = 'right', 
                                                  partial = TRUE, 
                                                  na.rm = TRUE)),
   by = id,
   .SDcols = col_names]
```

However, I get the error:

```
Error in weighted.mean.default(data[replace(posns, !ix, 0)], ...) : 
  'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

Is it because .SD is a data.table and `weighted.mean()` doesn't work for data.tables?

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: According to `?weighted.mean` `w - a numerical vector of weights the same length as x giving the weights to use for elements of x.`. Here, you are providiing a vector of length 3 and it could vary between each 'id'

Comment: rollapplyr is from zoo package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we remove the `partial = TRUE`, it should work along with adding `fill = NA`

```
library(data.table)
DT[, (col_names) := lapply(.SD, 
                           function(x) rollapplyr(x, 
                                                  width = 3,
                                                  weighted.mean, 
                                                  w = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5),
                                                  align = 'right', 
                                                  fill = NA
                                                  )),
   by = id,
   .SDcols = col_names]
```

With `partial = TRUE`, the 'w' length is same as 3 and there is no subsetting which creates the error in length difference between 'x' and 'w'

Comment: well thanks again. It works - provided I do something about the integer types! Not the first time :)